# How to run kivy after 1.9.1 on windows?

Tags: python, environment-variables, kivy

After the installation of Kivy 1.9.1 on Windows using the commands of Kivy installation tutorials, I can't run the program using "kivy ***.py". I don't know how to set up the environment variables, and I can't find it on the official websites.

- Kivy: 1.9.1
- Python: 3.4.4
- Windows 10

Please HELP!

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried "python ***.py"?

Comment: If you get an error please show the error message. Otherwise we can't really say what's wrong. Otherwise there is a [this documentation dedicated to installing kivy on windows](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html). Did you follow the steps (especially [making python available everywhere](https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html#making-python-available-anywhere)?)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're running the command from the folder where the ***.py file is located, "kivy ***.py" should run from there.

Answer (score 0):

To run kivy application on windows it's simply

```
python *.py
```

But on MacOS it should be

```
kivy *.py
```